# How to uncomment formatted code?

Tags: java, eclipse, comments

My code appears like this

```
/*
* if (isLoggingDebug()) { logDebug("Total Records : " +
* totalRecords); }
*/
```

T have several blocks of commented code like above and I need to remove the comments. Each time I find it difficult to remove the `*` in each line after using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

Comment: What editor are you using? (I'm sure ctrl + shift + (backslash) is an editor oriented shortcut. )

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your question to improve readability.

Comment: In eclipse use `Ctrl + /` to toggle the comments.

Comment: @AbhinavSarkar That's `Ctrl + /`.

Comment: I'm just worried about the * symbol which appears after formatting my commented lines

Answer (score 3):

for a moderate amount of code the find and Replace Feature of eclipse or any other reasonable editor might come in handy: search for `'* '` and replace it with  `''`.

Many of the more powerful editors also allow to select a rectangular range and manipulate (in this case delete it. This would allow you to select the rectangular block from 0,0 to 3,0 in the example and delete it. You could look into vi, emacs, ultraedit, [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) and many more.

Comment: The stackoverflow way to say "Thanks your post helped" is to upvote it using the up arrow left of the question. :-)

Comment: This will break `foo = bar * baz;` and any other non-comment location containing `* `.

Answer (score 0):

For single line comment you can use Ctrl + / and for multiple line comment you can use Ctrl + Shift + / after selecting the lines you want to comment in java editor.

Comment: for me this just toggles additional // before all lines.